# Missing delegate block call will crash the app. Is it possible to declare block like @optional when using @protocol?

Tags: iphone, xcode, delegates, objective-c-blocks

I'm writing class for dragable object.

When panning is finished I want to delegate it using blocks.
It's working fine, but how should I set something like @optional when using @protocol?
Because if I don't call myObject.didEndPanning app crash.

```
// MyClass.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^DelegateBlock)(void);

@interface AHDraggableObject : UIView

- (id)initDragableView:(UIView *)view inView:(UIView *)parentView withBorderOffset:(int)offset;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *holder;
@property (nonatomic, weak) DelegateBlock didEndPanning;

@end

// MyClass.m

- (void)handlePanning:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:_parentView];
    sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translation.x, sender.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:_parentView];

    [self checkBondaries:sender withOffset:_offset inView:_parentView];

    //  end of pan - invoke event
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        _didEndPanning();
    }
}
```

Call

```
//ViewController.m
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    _drag = [[MRShape alloc] initDragableView:_testImageView inView:self.view withBorderOffset:40];
    _drag.didEndPanning = ^
    {
     // if didEndPanning call is missing, app crash !
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether the block has been set:

```
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded && _didEndPanning)
{
    _didEndPanning();
}
```